# Case expression must be constant expression

Tags: android, eclipse

My project was successfully running but suddenly it got error and it shows, case expression must be constant expression, i remember that i din't do any changes please help me.
(my eclipse version is JUNO)

thank you

Comment: Post the crash log or the code segment

Comment: is it related to run time generated files R.java ? if yes then clean and build again. or close project, open again and build

Comment: show us the error and the code segment that is raising the error..

Comment: Hey friends thanks for the heads up, i have fixed it, just an XML error which was misspelled and eclipse dint show it as an error that's the problem i found and rectified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found, that might have replaced any source files or folder and it will not be updated correctly,
the only way is to recreate a new project and put all the old code in the new project.